# SipJs not working in kony browser for Android kitkat

Tags: javascript, android, webrtc, sip, temenos-quantum

- We use Sipjs for chat application.
- SipJs works fine with the higher version of Android kitkat like
  Lollipop, Marshmallow. But not works in kitkat.
- Actually Kony browser which internally invokes native OS browser.
  This application works fine in the native chrome browser.
- Someone, Please help me.

  ```
  Client1.html
  (function () {
           var queue= [];
           var ipaddress="1111";
           var url=ipaddress+"@sipjs.onsip.com";
          var sysIpaddress="2222"+"@sipjs.onsip.com";
               var userAgent = new SIP.UA({
          traceSip: true,
          uri: sysIpaddress,
          displayName: ipaddress,
          register:false  
      });
      var aliceInput=document.getElementById('alice-message-input');
      var aliceButton=document.getElementById('alice-message-button');
      aliceButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if(userAgent.isConnected()){
          sendMessage();
      }
  }); 
  function sendMessage() {
          var msg = aliceInput.value;
          // Only send a message if the message is non-empty
          if (msg !== '') {
              aliceInput.value = '';
              userAgent.message(url, msg);
          }
    }
  }) ();
  ```

```
     Client2.html
    (function () {
      var queue= {
        'queueArray':[]
      }
     var ipaddress="2222";
     var url=ipaddress+"@sipjs.onsip.com";
     var sysIpaddress="1111"+"@sipjs.onsip.com";
        var userAgent = new SIP.UA({
            traceSip: true,
            uri: sysIpaddress,
            displayName: ipaddress,
            register:true 
        });
        var aliceInput=document.getElementById('alice-message-input');
      userAgent.on('message', function (msg) {
        var userAgentreceivertextarea=document.getElementById('alice-message-output');
        userAgentreceivertextarea.value=msg.body;
      });
    }) ();
```

Actually, It sends but not receiving the message.

TraceSip Log:

```
 [INFO:CONSOLE(36)] "Mon Oct 03 2016 11:16:58 GMT+0530 (IST) | sip.transport | sending WebSocket message:
 MESSAGE sip:1111@sipjs.onsip.com SIP/2.0
 Via: SIP/2.0/WSS 29pclh5bd8j9.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK3748080
 Max-Forwards: 70
 To: <sip:1111@sipjs.onsip.com>
 From: "1111" <sip:2222@sipjs.onsip.com>;tag=7dsaoa1ptu
 Call-ID: 3cq7v58lhccl09f16c6o
 CSeq: 3235 MESSAGE
 Content-Type: text/plain
 Supported: outbound
 User-Agent: SIP.js/0.7.0
 Content-Length: 3

 Hai
 ", source: file:///android_asset/sip-0.7.0.min.js (36)



 [INFO:CONSOLE(36)] "Mon Oct 03 2016 11:16:58 GMT+0530 (IST) | sip.transport | received WebSocket text message:
 SIP/2.0 404 Not Found
 Via: SIP/2.0/WSS 29pclh5bd8j9.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK3748080
 To: <sip:1111@sipjs.onsip.com>;tag=3e56624696354839164e94cd00148538.7ca4
 From: "1111" <sip:2222@sipjs.onsip.com>;tag=7dsaoa1ptu
 Call-ID: 3cq7v58lhccl09f16c6o
 CSeq: 3235 MESSAGE
 Server: OpenSIPS (1.10.0-notls (x86_64/linux))
 Content-Length: 0

 ", source: file:///android_asset/sip-0.7.0.min.js (36)
```

Comment: Do you get any error in console? or Show us what's happening in the console after you send message, Since you have tracesip enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have attached tracesip log.

Comment: `SIP/2.0 404 Not Found` comes from Opensips, So you need to compare Working log vs non working log. It actually says user not available. But how come its working in Chrome browser?